# Add a space at thousand separate point instead comma for whole application

Tags: c#

I want add a space at thousand separate point instead comma.

Use bellow setting

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FormatSettings.Default.NumberGroupSeparator))
                RootServiceProvider.Culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = FormatSettings.Default.NumberGroupSeparator;
```

Setting file is like below.

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]

        public string NumberGroupSeparator
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(this["NumberGroupSeparator"]));
            }
            set
            {
                this["NumberGroupSeparator"] = value;
            }
        }
```

---

```
<setting name="NumberGroupSeparator" serializeAs="String">
<value> </value>
</setting>
```

When this execute it adding following line. **Weird thing is this happens sometimes.not always.**

```
"\r\n               "
```

How to solve this. I tried

```
<value>&#x20;</value>
```

Gives the same thing.
Is there any better way to do this?